# Plugin map my post (wordpress) doesn't work: MissingKeyMapError

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am new to the forum and I have a problem with the Wordpress extension Map My Posts.

The widget does not display the Google map but the message "Oops! Something went wrong. This page Did not load Google Maps Correctly. See the JavaScript console for technical details. " as you can see on my site http://blog-voyages-claude.fr/

With or without API key in the setting of the extension, I receive the following error message in the JavaScript console:

v js = 3 & sensor = false: 32 Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/docu ... -map-error

Answer (score 0):

It may have something to do with this:

> HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfil it.
>   GET - http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?key=AIzaSyAhOBYIRBg10X2tadL5si38t6TN4tXBKNw&size=300x250&markers=color%3Apurple%7C39.4%2C-8.2&sensor=false

Further inspection of that 403 response shows this:

> The Google Maps API server rejected your request.
>   This API project is not authorized to use this API.
>   Please ensure that this API is activated in the APIs Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library?project=_
>   Please ensure this API is activated in the Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/static_maps_backend?project=_

Proceed as instructed and this should fix the problem.